# Is it Possible to put entire Jqgrid in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, editing

I am working on an ASP.net MVC Application and using jqgrid in it. I wanted to do bulk edit for my grid.

I am aware that jqgrid support `inline editing,cell editing and Popupform editing` .

Is there any option that sets entire jqgrid in edit mode and after making changes , save them back to data base.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `editRow` option in loop in the `loadComplete` like,

```
$("#jQGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '../Controller/Action',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: [...],
    colModel: [...],
     .
     .
     .
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true,
    loadComplete: function () { 

        //just make all the row to editmode

        ids = $("#jQGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        var l = ids.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            $("#jQGrid").jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
        }
    },
    rowNum: 10
});
```